# IRtdServer.RefreshData and format cell

Tags: c#, excel, rtd

Can RefreshData function send Excel cell format information. I want excel to show arrows in his cells and I want RTD server to inform him which arrow to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer on msdn social http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exceldev/thread/36f483c0-e50c-40e6-985f-eef82cf3bf63